# Import Optional and some other packages are not working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

It was working properly but all of a sudden it stopped recognizing some packages like Optional,java.nio.Files,Paths,java.util.Stream etc.I tried almost all other's solution like cleaning up the project but nothing worked for me.The class java.nio.Files and other packages that are not recognizing by eclipse are even missing from classes.jar in JRE system library.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using JDK in version 1.7 or higher?

Comment: Install the JDK instead of the JRE?

Comment: JDK 1.8 and in the eclipse build path it is showing java SE 1.6

Comment: What have you set it to use under Java > Compiler > compliance level?

Comment: compiler compliance level is 1.8

Comment: Did you update your Java installation, so it's now in a different folder? In Eclipse, check `Window` → `Preferences` → `Java` → `Installed JREs`, and verify that the `Location` of the listed JRE is valid, and the correct version of Java.

Comment: I didn't do any update.It was working perfectly but suddenly after 2 mins it started showing errors in my project.I have checked Installed JRES,it is showing java se 1.6,1.7,1.8 and the compatible JRE is java  SE 6.0

Comment: I myself solved this issue.I had both JDK 1.6 and 1.8 in my system.In the windows->preferences,I replaced JDK 1.6 with JD 1.8 location path.But still, I don't have the clue on why it stopped to work with JDK 1.6 which was working fine earlier.